# free() doesn't accept type of structure

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct STATE STATE;
typedef struct TRANSITION TRANSITION;

struct STATE {
    char name[4];
    bool initial_state;
    bool final_state;
    TRANSITION *transitions;
    int numberTransitions;
};

struct TRANSITION {
    char c;
    STATE *destination;
};

STATE *create_state(char *name, bool is_initial, bool is_final);
void add_transition(STATE *source, char sign, STATE *dest);
void destroy_state(STATE **pp_state);

STATE *create_state(char *name, bool is_initial, bool is_final) {
    STATE *state = malloc(sizeof(STATE));
    strcpy(state->name, name);
    state->initial_state = is_initial;
    state->final_state = is_final;
    state->transitions = NULL;
    state->numberTransitions = 0;
    return state;
}

void add_transition(STATE *source, char sign, STATE *dest) {
    if (source->transitions == NULL) {
        TRANSITION *transitions = malloc(sizeof(TRANSITION));
        transitions->c = sign;
        transitions->destination = malloc(sizeof(STATE));
        transitions->destination = dest;
        source->transitions = transitions;
        source->numberTransitions = 1;
    } else {
        TRANSITION *transitions = source->transitions;
        int numberTransitions = source->numberTransitions;
        size_t new_size = sizeof(transitions) + sizeof(TRANSITION);
        transitions = realloc(transitions, new_size);
        transitions[numberTransitions].c = sign;
        transitions[numberTransitions].destination = dest;
        (source->numberTransitions)++; 
    }
}

void destroy_state(STATE **pp_state) {
    TRANSITION *transitions = (*pp_state)->transitions;
    int numberTransitions = (*pp_state)->numberTransitions;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < numberTransitions; i++) {
        free(transitions[i]);
        transitions[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

My exception says that the type of `transitions[i]` is incompatible with the methods parameter. What is wrong with that method call? Transitions is a structure.

**EDIT:** I added the other methods because it was requested.

**EDIT2:** OK, I found out if my STATE has only one TRANSITION, I can free the TRANSITION pointer. So my guess is that I do a mistake with the reallocation when I try to realloc the memory for my additional transition.

```
size_t new_size = sizeof(transitions) + sizeof(TRANSITION);
transitions = realloc(transitions, new_size);
```

Comment: Cannot see the `malloc` - I am foxed

Comment: You cam only `free` what is returned by `malloc`. Do you have `transitions[i] = malloc(...)`? No? Don't free it then

Answer (score 3):

```
free(transitions[i]);
```

`transitions[i]` is not any pointer type to be passed to `free` . `transitions` is a pointer to structure but `transition[i]` becomes structure variable(*not pointer type*) and thus should not be passed to `free` .

Do this -

```
free(transitions);
```

Comment: @DennisvonEich You allocate memory to `transitions`(`free` needed only here) not to `transitions[i]`(_therefore no need to `free` it ._) . **You should `free` only what you have allocated using `malloc` or family.**

Comment: For each malloc, you must have a related free. Count the number of malloc you do.

Comment: I get the runtime exception "Aborted"

Comment: @DennisvonEich Did you remove loop ? Loop remains useless in this case .

Comment: I did remove the loop.

Comment: If I allocate memory for a structure that has a structure as a component that also needs allocation, do I have to free both or is it enough to free the "owner"?

Comment: @DennisvonEich You have to `free` both , and you need to `free` struct member before freeing struct pointer .

Comment: I see, but I simply can't do free(transitions); It always Abort

Answer (score 1):

You can't free single item (value) from an array.

You can only free the value it points too if it's pointer or free full array at once:

```
       free(transitions);
```

Or change transitions to array of pointers and you can do the former:

```
 TRANSITION **transitions;
```

Answer (score 1):

The rule is to free what you have malloc-ed. Here you realloc the array of struts `transition`, not an individual `transition`.

So when freeing, you must use:

```
free(transition);
```

BTW, what you pass to free **must** be a pointer that will be silently cast to a `void *`. `transition` is an array that can decay to pointer, but `transition[i]` is a struct and it cannot be cast to an array. That's what the compilation error means. If you have use `free(&(transition[i]))` or `free(transition + 1)` you would have no compilation error, but it would invoke undefined behaviour since you would try to free a pointer to a memory that has not been obtained through `malloc`

Answer (score 0):

You can't `free` a struct, you can free pointers. Either free the internal `STATE destination`, or the entire `transitions` array, or both.

Comment: My STATE structure has a list of TRANSITION. As you can see it is a pointer. If I simply free the pointer, do I free every single TRANSITION in the list?

Comment: You should pass `free` the exact pointer you got back from `malloc` or `realloc`.